# Why are my options for Frames not showing in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Here is the code for the UI design that I am making:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import sqlite3
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import winsound

##-------------Frames setup--------------------------
class VendingApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Store)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        #Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one.
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class Store(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self._images = list()

        img_banner = Image.open("pic/banner.jpg")
        img_banner = img_banner.resize((400, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        banner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_banner)

        img_logo = Image.open("pic/sitelogo.png")
        img_logo = img_logo.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_logo)

        self._images.append(logo)
        self._images.append(banner)

        ##---------------------Top frame Home------------------------------------
        topFrame = Frame(self, width=500, height=100)
        topFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        topFrame.grid_propagate(False)

        canvas_for_logo = Canvas(topFrame, height=100, width=100, bg='green')  ##logo image
        canvas_for_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        canvas_for_logo.grid_propagate(False)

        canvas_for_logo.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=logo)

        canvas_for_banner = Canvas(topFrame, height=100, width=400 ) # banner image
        canvas_for_banner.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw')
        canvas_for_banner.grid_propagate(False)

        canvas_for_banner.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=banner)
 ##---------------------------------Midd-------------------

        LeftSide = Frame(self,width = 150, height = 450, relief = RAISED, bg = 'grey')
        LeftSide.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        RightSide = Frame(self,width = 350, height = 450, bg = 'red')
        RightSide.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        BottomFrame = Frame(self,width = 500, height = 50, bg = 'black')
        BottomFrame.grid(row = 2, column =0, columnspan = 2)

        test_btn = Button(BottomFrame, command = None, bg = 'green', width = 5, height = 5)
        test_btn.pack()



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = VendingApp()
    #Renames the TITLE of the window
    root.title("Vending machine")
    root.geometry("500x600")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why is the **RAISE** relief on the left frame not showing? (edit: This question is answered)
2. Why does the bg on the left and right frame change but not the bottom one? (edit: this question is answered)
3. if you replace to logo and banner with any picture, I believe that you'd see there is a gap of empty space on both said of the logo, one between the edge of the logo and the app, one between the logo and the banner. Why is it happening? (edit: I did some more research and have finally found the solution for this)

Every response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid_propagate(0) and test_btn.grid()

```
    BottomFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
    BottomFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    test_btn = Button(BottomFrame, command=None, bg='green', width=5, height=5)
    test_btn.grid()
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. I asked my teacher in class and he says that because I was using pack() for my button but the propagation options were for grid(), hence why it didn't have any effect on the buttons. Apparently, grid/pack_propagate only affects things that are in/on the object and not the object itself. Thank you for your response regardless, much appreciated.

Comment: As I already said: it is better to use one only geometry in a program to make things more easy to fix or change.

Answer (score 1):

1. you must add a `bd=5` (border size)
2. First do not mix `pack()` and `grid()`. Second, when you add a btn to bottom frame, the frame takes the size of the button. You must use `BottomFrame.propagate(0)` to ignore the button size.

Comment: The mixing of `pack` and `grid` in this program is perfectly fine since they are being used in different widgets.

Comment: @hussic thank you for your response. The border size advice worked perfectly. However, when I changed the propagation property of the bottom frame to false, the button still proceeds to resize the frame, any idea why?